# C# Skipping parts of code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got stucked - the first part of the code "**// OPEN PRELOADING PAGE**" will for some reason not execute and will be skipped. If I comment the rest of the code and only keep this part there, it works. What is wrong?

```
protected void Create_Order_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // OPEN PRELOADING PAGE
  Response.Write("<script>");
  Response.Write("window.open('smth.aspx','_blank')");
  Response.Write("</script>");

  // DEFINE CONNECTION
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
             .ConnectionStrings["SqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

  // OPEN CONNECTION
  conn.Open();

  // DEFINE FIRST SQL QUERY
  string insertOrder = "INSERT INTO Order_Connection (FK_User_ID) VALUES ('" + Session["User_ID"] + "')";

  string str = FileUpload1.FileName;
  FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "//upload//" + str);
  string path = "//xxx.cz/intranet/pages/upload/" + str.ToString();

  string insertOrder_Content = "INSERT INTO Order_Content (Uploaded_Photo, Issue_Description, Place_Of_Repair, Transfer_Method, Date_To_Bring, Date_To_Take) VALUES ('" + path + "', @Issue_Description, @Place_Of_Repair, @Transfer_Method, @Date_To_Bring, @Date_To_Take)";
  SqlCommand comInsertIntoOrder = new SqlCommand(insertOrder_Content, conn);

  comInsertIntoOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Issue_Description", TextBox_Issue_Description.Text);
  comInsertIntoOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Place_Of_Repair", DropDownList_Place.SelectedItem.ToString());
  comInsertIntoOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transfer_Method", DropDownList_Transfer.SelectedItem.ToString());
  comInsertIntoOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_To_Bring", TextBox_Date_To_Bring.Text);
  comInsertIntoOrder.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_To_Take", TextBox_Date_To_Take.Text);

  comInsertIntoOrder.ExecuteNonQuery();

  // EXECUTE FIRST SQL QUERY
  SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertOrder, conn);

  // EXECUTE NOW
  com.ExecuteNonQuery();

  // CLOSE CONNECTION
  conn.Close();

  Response.Redirect("http://xxx.cz/intranet/pages/Success.aspx");
}
```

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Redirects cannot have a response.

Comment: What is smth.aspx? Do you have a lot of code in it?

Answer (score 7):

You're calling `Response.Redirect` at the end of the method. That's going to basically terminate the request with a 302 response. The data you'd previously written to the (buffered) response is irrelevant at that point.

Additionally, you should look into parameterized SQL - your database handling is currently vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. (Always, always, always parameterize your SQL, basically.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you maybe also help me to do it correctly (redirect part). I first need to open 'smth.aspx' on _blank, then execute the rest of the code on original page and once it is done, redirect the original page to "http://xxx.cz/intranet/pages/Success.aspx"

Comment: @MartinHlavačka: It sounds like you basically need to learn more about HTTP - you're talking about multiple requests and responses at that point. You probably want to send a complete response which opens the other page and also calls back to the server using Javascript to check the status of the SQL part.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to achieve two things here;

1. Open a new tab and load 'smth.aspx'
2. Redirect the request to success.aspx

On Response.Redirect server sends back the browser only a `302 Response` something like this `HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://xxx.cz/intranet/pages/Success.aspx` and then browser sends another request to the `success.aspx` page. But you are expecting `smith.aspx` in a new tab with `success.aspx` in the page which won't happen as server never sent your script tag to the browser.
If that's what you're looking to do, then try this code;

```
Response.Write("<script>");
Response.Write("window.open('smth.aspx','_blank')");
Response.Write("window.location.href='success.aspx';");
Response.Write("</script>");
.... //remaining code
//Remove the Response.Redirect line at the end of your function.
```